# What's the difference between distributed computing and cloud computing?

Tags: cloud, computer-science, distributed-computing, terminology, definition

What is the difference between distributed computing and cloud computing?

Answer (score 5):

**Distributed computing** is when multiple autonomous machines communicate through a central network to perform a common goal.

**Cloud Computing** is more about computing as a service, that is given to a computer over a network.

For example, a distributed computing network might be 10,000 people processing SETI data on their computers through a screen saver.  And cloud computing might be when a million Apple users save all their MP3s to iCloud, rather than on their laptops.

I think the two sound more related than they are.

Answer (score 4):

> The main difference between *cloud computing* and *distributed computing* is that the **cloud computing** provides hardware, software and other infrastructure resources over the internet while the **distributed computing** divides a single task among multiple computers that are connected via a network to achieve the task faster than using an individual computer.
>
> **Cloud computing** helps to access hardware and software resources remotely via the network. It provides advantages such as easy resource sharing, cost reduction, scalability, and platform independence. A **distributed computing**, on the other hand, is a network with multiple computers to achieve a goal. Each computer in the network performs a section of the overall tasks. This method helps to obtain results faster than using a single computer. It provides advantages such as scalability, redundancy and resource sharing.

Source: [Difference Between Cloud Computing and Distributed Computing](https://pediaa.com/difference-between-cloud-computing-and-distributed-computing/)

Comment: This is word by word copied from https://pediaa.com/difference-between-cloud-computing-and-distributed-computing/ . You should at least include reference to original source in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Distributed Computing:

Is a system/solution that is able to borrow resources for processing from other systems/solutions. Usually by delegation and using communication distribution systems or networks.

#### Cloud Computing:

Are the product/services and resources provided from such a system.

#### More

Distributed computing can be as complex and robust as an operating system which basically could allow you to combine several computers to act as one. Or, as simple as an application which borrows free resources from other systems it can communicate with and has a "contract" with. Contract is not a technical term for it, I just find it fitting. The distributed computing doesn't necessarily depend on all its parts and may operate independently, but is able to delegate tasks to other parts of its system.

Cloud Computing is built from/with distributed computing. Technically, if you have an application which syncs up information across several of your devices you are doing cloud computing and since it is using distributed computing.

Now to tighten up that head vice. You can build a distributed system using cloud computing. Infinite loop! It's not that crazy since you could basically build a distributed system out of other distributed systems. **It's a system of systems**.

### Note:

I felt compelled to answer this since I felt like every other answer was missing one thing or another. I hope, I didn't do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with defining what these two terms mean exactly. The difference will start becoming apparent from the definitions itself.

Cloud computing is a system where different things like software applications, infrastructure resources, or development tools are provided to the user via the Internet. Traditionally, if a user wanted to run a software application, it was mandatory for them to make sure that they fulfill all the extensive software and hardware requirements that are necessary for running that single application. 
But, with cloud, that’s not the case anymore since the application can be accessed simply through an Internet connection. The user no longer has to worry about any software or hardware installation on their personal system to avail the application.

It’s not only software applications that can be accessed over the Internet, but many other things too like databases, servers, software development resources, data centers, etc. In fact, cloud offerings are of three types, software as a service (SaaS), infrastructure as a service (IaaS), and platform as a service (PaaS).

Next, let’s define distributed computing. This is a kind of system where a single software system has components distributed across a number of computers, but they all execute as a consolidated system. These distributed components of the software are connected with each other through a network. Therefore, the computers over which the software components are spread across will have a way for communicating with each other and ensuring that there is synchronization between the software components. Depending on whether the computers are located nearby in same location or away from each other in different locations, the network connecting the computers could be a local area network or a wide area network. Distributed computing systems can be of three kinds: distributed computing systems, distributed pervasive systems, and distributed information systems.

Now, that we understand the definitions of distributed computing and cloud computing, hopefully the distinction between these two computing models has become clearer already. While cloud computing refers to the delivery of necessary resources via the Internet, distributed computing refers to sharing of resources between the systems via a connecting network. Each of these computing models has unique set of benefits to offer.

Scalability is one of the most prominent advantages of [cloud computing solutions](https://www.cisin.com/service/infrastructure-automaiton-and-cloud.htm). Depending upon increasing or decreasing resource demands, it is possible to get access to more or less software, storage, network, and other computing resources over the Internet.

**Cost-efficiency and simplicity are some other advantages of this model.**

Distributed computing too offers scalability, in the sense that you can add or remove computer systems in the network depending on the current requirements. Distributed software applications also ensure better performance and resilience.